# All connected subsets of $[-2,-1] \cup [1,2]$

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Let $X=[-2,-1] \cup [1,2]$. Find the shape of the connected subsets of X.

We can see $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So all connected subsets of $X$ are intervals or singletons, then connected subsets are intervals such that is a subset of $[-2,-1]$ or $[1,2]$

Am I right?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.